# How to adjust the text Order Summary in shopping cart

Tags: order-summary, magento234

All the text in the Order Summary is dutch, so i want to change ´´Order Summary´´ into ´´Order Totaal``
I cannot find the solution.

For all with the same problem. I managed this problem with function inline translation in backend magento. Thanks for all responding.

Answer (score 0):

To change the Order Summary title on the checkout page copy the code from

```
vendor/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary.html
```

to

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/template/summary.html
```

and then under the new file change

```
<span data-bind="i18n: 'Order Summary'" class="title"></span>
```

to

```
<span data-bind="i18n: 'Order Totaal'" class="title"></span>
```

Comment: I my folder app/design/frontend/Magento is empty, so where to copy too?

Comment: Which is the new file named? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to create a new custom theme if you do not already have one in order to make changes to the Magento code. Then you would copy the code to the above folder replacing "Vendor" with the name vendor name of your theme and "Theme" with the theme name. Here is a link to create a new storefront theme in Magento 2. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

Comment: Thanks. I find the solution by another way as inline translation. But thanks for your response!

Comment: If my solution worked will you select it as the correct answer. I would appreciate it :)

Comment: For me this was not the solution Josiah. I find a better manner to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

"Order Summary","Order Totaal"

add above translation in your translation csv file , which is in app/design/frontend/[your theme]/i18n/[your csv file name]

after run the below commands,

bin/magento c:f

bin/magento s:s:d -f

bin/magento c:f